# Multi-Pointer X flickering

Tags: xinput, multipointerx

*I know this topic is kind of old, but I'd like to know if there were any news in the last decade or so. My Ubuntu version is 20.04.3 LTS.*

I want to use multiple pointer like described in [this Multi-Pointer X article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Multi-pointer_X). It was easy to add a second pointer and reattach it with `xinput`.

However, the second pointer is flickering a lot. The previous named article suggest deactivating Compton, but I couldn't find something comparable to deactivate in my current Ubuntu version. I've also tried to use `xinput set-cp` to use a pointer for only one window, but it had no effect.

Comment: @Community Done.

Comment: Not a lot of apps support MPX to my knowledge, so glitchy behaviour is to be expected. This is one of the bugs MPX has. There is no way to fix it unless you use an app that supports MPX (Only Gromit-MPX to my knowledge)